# Variable no definida en class PHP

Tags: mysqli, php5

En PHP 5.5 tengo un archivo **conexion.php** con la conexion a mi base de datos.

```
<?php
$usuario = "userDB";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "myDB";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basededatos) or die("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
?>
```

Y con include lo llamo en un class en otro archivo  **consultas.php**

```
<?php
class consultas {
    public function consultaCorreo($correo) {
        include 'conexion.php';
        if ($correo) {
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT correo FROM usuario WHERE correo=?');
            $statement->bind_param('s', $correo);
            $statement->execute();
            $rs = $statement->get_result();

    }
}
?>
```

**consultas.php** me indica que la variable **$conexion** (definida en conexion.php) no esta inicializada. Por lo mismo no ejecuta el query.

¿Alguna idea de porque pasa esto?

Comment: Prueba a poner `include 'conexion.php';` al principio del script y fíjate si está bien puesta la dirección del recurso.

Comment: en tu archivo `consultas.php` no se ve que hagas `include` de `conexion.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría ser una solución:

```
class Conexion
{
    public $usuario = "userDB";
    public $password = "";
    public $servidor = "localhost";
    public $basededatos = "myDB";
    public $conexion;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conexion = mysqli_connect(
                $this->servidor,
                $this->usuario,
                $this->password,
                $this->basededatos
        ) or die("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->conexion;
    }
}

class consultas
{
    public function consultaCorreo($correo)
    {
        $newConexion = new Conexion();
        $conexion = $newConexion->getConnection();

        if ($correo) {
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT correo FROM usuario WHERE correo=?');
            $statement->bind_param('s', $correo);
            $statement->execute();
            $rs = $statement->get_result();
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes separar la clase **Conexion** otro archivo y llamarlo desde donde quieras.